# TypeError: someDate.getTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I encounter this error when using my app on device even though it works just fine in browser, what might be the reason behind that?

```
public someDate: Date = new Date();
```

then in other place:

```
console.log(Math.floor(this.settingsService.someDate.getTime() / 60000) * 60000);
```

and error:

```
TypeError: this.settingsService.someDate.getTime is not a function
    at Promise (main.js:26956)
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at Data.initialPing (main.js:26949)
    at TrackerPage.startWork (main.js:39881)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TrackerPage.html:21)
    at handleEvent (main.js:12340)
    at callWithDebugContext (main.js:13632)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (main.js:13220)
    at dispatchEvent (main.js:9240)
    at main.js:9832
```

Comment: Are you sure that your settingsService is correctly imported? have you tried `console.log(someDate)` to see what is inside? or maybe even `console.dir(this.settingsService)` to see if all is correct?

Comment: yes, everything is correct, and this code works in browser testing, it just doesn't work on my mobile device, and I have same error when using other date object functions like .getDate() or getMonth()

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the answer, the reason it was working in browser but not in mobile device is that the mobile device is storing dates differently in its memory:

```
2017-08-07T10:26:06.564Z
```